# Where does this risk cost function come from?

Tags: microeconomics

I was trying to understand this risk cost function:

[image]

I suppose that comes from Relative Risk Aversion coefficient:

[image]

But I need help to understand the intuition behind de cost function and how it is derived.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some context in which the formula is used. Note also that $-\frac{U''(x)}{U'(x)}$ is the [coefficient of *absolute* risk aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Absolute_risk_aversion), and $Var(X)$ is sometimes used as a measure of risk contained in random variable $X$.

Comment: Where did you find this cost function?